# How to extend JavaScript literal (object) with a new variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, literals, javascript-objects, object-literal

I have JavaScript variable as a literal:

```
var global = {
    getTime : function() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        return currentDate.getTime();
    }
};
```

And I wish to extend this literals with other different functions, which are going to be created as variables:

```
var doSomething = function(param){
    $("#" + param).hide();
    return "hidden";
}
```

**How can I extend my literal with a new variable, which holds a function?!**
At the end I wish to use this in such a way:

```
alert( global.doSomething("element_id") );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend your `global` variable with the method `doSomething`, you should just do this:

```
global.doSomething = doSomething;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nslr/nADQW/

Answer (score 4):

```
var global = {
    dothis: function() {
        alert('this');
    }
}

var that = function() {
    alert('that');
};

var global2 = {
    doSomething: that
};

$.extend(global, global2);


$('#test').click(function() {
    global.doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global.doSomething = function(param){
```

or

```
var doSomething = function(param){ ...
global.doSomething = doSomething;
```